# Scene reset function not working

Tags: unity

I am entirely new to programming. Recently just watched [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR0e-1UBEOU&t=4826) and follow the way the author wrote the code until (1:22:24). I'm not sure why the scene reset function for trasnform.position.y > 10 not working for me. The compiler does not detect any error and game run as normal but the scene does not reset when the bird position on y axis more than 10. I'm using another bird object anwyay since i can't find exactly the same bird picture as author did. Also is there a way to check what the value store in each variable?  Example I want to check what the value stored in "transform.position.y" to find out why it is not working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    
public class GreenBird : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 _initialPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y > 10)
        {
            string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * 100);
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is called update(). It should be Update(). Unity never runs it, because that upper case matters.